# 2006 KIA wouldn't stay idle after each fueling (only)

Tags: repair, old-cars

After fueling, my car engine wouldn't stay idle after turn the key to start the ignition, it always die-out immediately that require a restart. On the restart, I need to peddle the gas pedal with one foot and keep the other on the brake, so it wouldn't die when I shift the transmission handle, then I need to give a hard push on the gas pedal and release the brake simultaneously to get the car going. The engine will stop if I don't pump the gas and hold the brake continuously for about 100 yards. Once on the road, everything is back to normal then.

There is no such problem during every start-up but after fueling. The idle speed is normal. What could have gone wrong?

Please let me know if this question is not suitable for this forum. Thanks.

Comment: Some air or liquid lock in the tank venting pipes?

Comment: @Solar Mike Where I can find the venting pipe? One comment on DIY forum suggests that a faulty computer chip can be the cause, What do you think?.

Comment: @jupiter Thanks for the tip. Seems easy to handle, I'll replace it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the EVAP purge valve is faulty allowing the engine to flood during fill up.